# Eventos en Adapters listView

Tags: java, android

Me encuentro en el dilema de tener un listview , con un adapter personalizado

tengo el siguiente adapter

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quisiera lograr es que si clikcea en el signo de aceptar , o si clickea en el signo de rechazar suceda algo ,

lo primero que pense es agregarl un onclick a cada imagen ,

esos iconos son imagenes , pero resulta que haciendolo asi , no sabre cual de todos los items del listView fue el clickedo , eh investigado y no eh encontrado algo que me guie a resolver dicho problema , cualquier ayuda de como poder solucionar este problema es bienvenida , desde ya gracias

esta es mi clase adapter

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtNumberPhoneBilling"
        android:layout_width="168dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="textview"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_weight="0.67" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMountBillingNotifications"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtNumberPhoneBilling"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:text="TextViewss"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="16dp"/>

<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/black"

    android:id="@+id/txtDateBillingNotifications"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtMountBillingNotifications"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnAcceptBillingNotifications"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/aceptar"
    android:onClick="Acept"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnCancelBillingNotifications"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/cancelar"
    android:onClick="Cancel"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```

y esta es mi clase de adapter

```
package banred.twoinnovateit.com.Utils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import banred.twoinnovateit.com.bimo.R;
/*
*Create by: Bruno Sosa
*Date: 17-10-2017
*Description: Clase de adapter del listado de cobros pendientes
*/

public class AdapterCobroPendiente extends BaseAdapter {

    protected Activity activity;
    protected ArrayList<CobroPendiente> items;

    public AdapterCobroPendiente(Activity activity, ArrayList<CobroPendiente> itemsCompra) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = itemsCompra;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getNumber());
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = contentView;

        if (contentView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_billing_notifications_adapter, null);
        }

        CobroPendiente item = items.get(position);

        TextView number = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtNumberPhoneBilling);
        number.setText(item.getNumber());

        TextView mount = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtMountBillingNotifications);
        mount.setText(item.getMonto());

        TextView date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtDateBillingNotifications);
        date.setText(item.getFecha());

        return vi;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bruno, agrega tu Adapter para que sea mejor tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya esta editado

Comment: Prueba a desarrollar solo un onClick y dentro metes un if y else if mirando si el evento que le llega es igual al findById (R.res.'lo que quieras')

Comment: no te entendi muy buen DazzaekWazzel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Era importante agregaras tu `Adapter` ya que precisamente aquí es donde puedes definir un `listener` para cada elemento de tu ListView, por ejemplo aquí puedes obtener la referencia de los `ImageView` con id `btnAcceptBillingNotifications` y `btnCancelBillingNotifications` se asigna un listener y puedes ver que botón se da click y de que elemento en el listado, en este ejemplo mediante un Toast.

```
      @Override
        public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi = contentView;

            if (contentView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_billing_notifications_adapter, null);
            }

            CobroPendiente item = items.get(position);

            TextView number = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtNumberPhoneBilling);
            number.setText(item.getNumber());

            TextView mount = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtMountBillingNotifications);
            mount.setText(item.getMonto());

            TextView date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtDateBillingNotifications);
            date.setText(item.getFecha());


 /*******************************/
 //Obtiene referencia de ImageView Aceptar.
 ImageView btnAcceptBillingNotifications = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.btnAcceptBillingNotifications);

 //Define Listener a ImageView.
    btnAcceptBillingNotifications.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Aceptar de elemento " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    })

 //Obtiene referencia de ImageView Cancelar.
 ImageView btnCancelBillingNotifications= (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelBillingNotifications);

 //Define Listener a ImageView.
    btnAcceptBillingNotifications.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Cancelar del elemento " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
    })



 /*******************************/
            return vi;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola lo que puedes hacer es enviar una interface al adapter para que el que crea el adapter sepa que pasa cuando se lanza alguna acción, algo así:

```
public interface BillingNotificationListener{

   void accepted(CobroPendiente cobroPendiente);

   void rejected(CobroPendiente cobroPendiente);
}
```

Luego en tu adapter puedes hacer algo así:

```
protected Activity activity;
protected ArrayList<CobroPendiente> items;
protected BillingNotificationListener billingNotificationListener;

public AdapterCobroPendiente(Activity activity, ArrayList<CobroPendiente> itemsCompra, BillingNotificationListener billingNotificationListener) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.items = itemsCompra;
    this.billingNotificationListener = billingNotificationListener;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return Integer.parseInt(items.get(position).getNumber());
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = contentView;

    if (contentView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_billing_notifications_adapter, null);
    }

    final CobroPendiente item = items.get(position);

    TextView number = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtNumberPhoneBilling);
    number.setText(item.getNumber());

    TextView mount = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtMountBillingNotifications);
    mount.setText(item.getMonto());

    TextView date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtDateBillingNotifications);
    date.setText(item.getFecha());

    View btnAcceptBillingNotifications = vi.findViewById(R.id.btnAcceptBillingNotifications);

    btnAcceptBillingNotifications.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                billingNotificationListener.accepted(item);
            }
    })

    return vi;
}
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: lo voy a chequear  gracias !